# How does emacs resume cursor position when we switch back to a buffer?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, emacs, emacsw32

I am not pretty sure whether this is just the correct reproduce process. Based on my observation, when I change between buffers, such as this scenario:

```
1. I am in Buffer1:position1
2. I switch to Buffer2:position2
3. I switch back to Buffer1
```

Now I am in `Buffer2` after step-2, and I do some edit jobs without using mouse to touch( selected or click ) the buffer content. Then, when I am back to `Buffer1`, I still in `position1`.

But If i have ever used mouse to do any action, when I back to `Buffer1`. I am not in the `position1` any more.

So is there any setting/variable about such problem?
What does the mouse( or maybe some other actions ) have changed, which result in changing the original position of another buffer?

This confuses my a long time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wonder why you need the mouse if you're using Emacs, however you can use registers to save your position in a file or bookmarks if you want to keep them between sessions. see `(info "(emacs) Position Registers")` and `(info "(emacs) Bookmarks")`.

Comment: I am using emacs under windows, as well as X window under Linux. Sometimes I may use mouse to select something to copy. But I don't think this should affect the position in another buffer which is not show in current window. On the other hand, I don't think the current emacs process is OK even I use mouse, I just want to know how can I make it correct.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, clicking in the buffer to return to it?  If so, you just told emacs where you want the cursor.

Comment: No, I just do action in buffer2, and never touch buffer1 with mouse. But when I change back, the cursor position changed. I want to know which action will affect the original position in a background buffer.

Comment: I can't make this happen using version 24.0.50.1 (built from source) on Windows.  Is it possible your two buffers have the same backing file?